# Apk partitioned in new Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build-process

Following are the logs when i run my application on a device from Android Studio

```
$ adb install-multiple -r 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_4.apk 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_3.apk
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_0.apk
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_7.apk
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_1.apk 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_5.apk 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_6.apk 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/dep/dependencies.apk 
app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_8.apk 
app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
```

What are these split APKs. Any more information regarding this plz. I dont have any split instructions in my gradle file. Can a single apk be partitioned into separate parts?

It has something to do with speeding up the build time for instant runs. As we can see there is a seperate APK for dependencies. So, the question is, what is happening under the hood?

UPDATE : I dont have any split apk instructions in my gradle file
This happens when i build project and run it

Comment: You should take a look over 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Updated question

Comment: It has something to do with instant run. Turning off instant run simply install `adb install app-debug.apk`. Also i am not able to install apk on physical device with instant run on. Are you facing similar issues?

Comment: Yes, wanted to know whats happening in the bg for speeding up instant run using the splits. I can see they have bundled the dependencies in a different apk. How are they managing it is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Click **Build** tab ---> **Clean Project**

Run.